# sort duplicates date wise

Tags: shell, sorting, unix, sh

I have a file with two-column elements(id and date). I want to sort those elements depending on its id, and in case several elements have the same id, they will be sorted depending on their dates.

I used `sort  -t" " -k2  -t"/" -k3 -k2 -k1 file.txt`  but that didn't work.
I don't know how to use filed separator.

input file

```
01/02/2012 1
02/03/2012 1
04/04/2012 1
01/02/2015 2
02/03/2014 2
04/04/2013 2
```

and output file should be :

```
01/02/2012 1                                                                                                                                                                                      
02/03/2012 1                                                                                                                                                                                      
04/04/2012 1                                                                                                                                                                                     
04/04/2013 2                                                                                                                                                                                      
02/03/2014 2                                                                                                                                                                                     
01/02/2015 2
```

Comment: your date format is terrible. Is it MM/DD/YYYY (USA is the only place on earth that uses that, as far as I know, and we (the rest of the world) usually don't like that format, but the US is really dominant), or is it DD/MM/YYYY (relatively logical format, sadly, confusable with the american one)?

Comment: @Marcus as per his expected output, I believe he uses DD/MM/YYYY. And that format they use in USA and Canada is MM/DD/YYYY: http://calendars.wikia.com/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Comment: There is a standard for dates - I wish everyone would use it! https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea: try to use *one* field separator (`sort` doesn't handle two or more different separators).

```
$  cat file                                                                                                                               
01/02/2012 1                                                                                                                                        
02/03/2012 1                                                                                                                                        
04/04/2012 1                                                                                                                                        
01/02/2015 2                                                                                                                                        
02/03/2014 2                                                                                                                                        
04/04/2013 2
$  sed 's, ,/,' file | sort -t '/' -k4 -k3 -k2 -k1 | sed 's,\(.*\)/\([^/]*\),\1 \2,'                                                      
01/02/2012 1                                                                                                                                        
02/03/2012 1                                                                                                                                        
04/04/2012 1                                                                                                                                        
04/04/2013 2                                                                                                                                        
02/03/2014 2                                                                                                                                        
01/02/2015 2
```

The first `sed` replace the space character to `/` than `sort` with `/` separator and the next `sed` replace the last `/` to space.

I don't know that your date format is `DD/MM/YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY` or  so maybe you want repace `-k4 -k3 -k2 -k1` to `-k4 -k3 -k1 -k2` in `sort` (I assume the first version).

Comment: Your last sed can be simplified if we are using GNU sed: replace the 3rd slash: `sed 's,/, ,3'`

Comment: Also, you might want to specify your fields more precisely: `-k 4,4 -k 3,3 -k 2,2 -k 1,1` -- as written sort sees `-k 4,4 -k 3,4 -k 2,4 -k 1,4`. Here, it's the same result, but this can bite you in other circumstances.

Comment: @glennjackman I'm using FreeBSD's `sed` - it doesn't support the `3` (number) flag.

Comment: How about `sed -E 's,(.*)/,\1 ,'` -- since `.*` is greedy, we know we have the last slash already.

Answer (score 1):

A similar idea to @uzsolt's answer, a Schwartzian transform

```
sed -r 's#([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})#\3\2\1 &#' file |
  sort -t " " -n -k 3,3 -k 1,1 |
  cut -d " " -f 2-
```

The first command adds a more sensible date to the start of the line:

```
01/02/2012 1    =>    20120201 01/02/2012 1
```

Then a simple numeric sort by field 3 then field 1.
Then cut off the newly added first field.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I'm pretty certain you can make a complicated expression that can instruct `sort` to understand the date, but you really shouldn't.

This is few lines in python which would be readable; something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from dateutil import parser
import sys

class comparable_line(object):
     def __init__(self, line):
         spacepos = line.find(" ")
         if spacepos < 0:
              raise ValueError("line must contain a space")
         self._num = int(line[spacepos+1:])
         self._date = parser.parse(line[:spacepos])

     def __cmp__(self, other):
         """" comparison method that is automatically called by python """"
         if self._num < other._num:
             return -1
         if self._num > other._num:
             return 1
         # at this point we know that the numbers are equal
         if self._date < other._date:
             return -1
         if self._date > other._date:
             return 1
         # totally equal: return equality (0)
         return 0
    def __str__(self):
         return "{num:d} {day:02d}/{month:02d}/{year:4d}".format(self._num, self._date.day, self._date.month, self._date.year)

sortedlines = [comparable_line(l) for l in sys.stdin].sort()
for line in sortedlines:
    print line
```

Warning: all out of back of my head. Untested. But this can deal with arbitrary sensible date formats (yours, by the way, is a terrible date format - is it MM/DD/YYYY, or DD/MM/YYYY ???).

So, input files like

```
2013-01-01/00:00:12 3
2013-01-01/00:00:15 3
```

would work!